# Error: not a statement when declaring a boolean in Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, boolean

The following code:

```
boolean continue = false;
```

Returns the following error:

```
error: not a statement
  boolean continue = false;
  ^
```

Why is this happening? I am pretty familiar with booleans.

Comment: 'continue' is a reserved keyword in Java, so using almost any other name should resolve that issue.

Comment: `continue` is a keyword, you can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: A syntax-highlighting editor makes problems like this more obvious.

Comment: I could say that continue is a reserved keyword, but instead I'd recommend using a proper IDE. Most IDE's will give you better (and instant) feedback about errors like this.

Comment: Thanks guys, i changed it and all is good. Since I am learning an introductory course for Java we have been told to not use Eclipse otherwise I would be. But now I know to never do that again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
boolean cont = false;
```

Or use another name. The point is that in Java, `continue` is a [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) and it can't be used as a variable name - it's right [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) in the language specification. For future [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) this is what `continue` is used for:

> The `continue` statement skips the current iteration of a `for`, `while`, or `do-while` loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the loop.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment? what is wrong with this answer, how can I improve it?

Comment: I think your answer is valid which is why I accepted it but I'm not sure why someone would down vote it?

Comment: @bradc14 a drive-by downvoter, or probably someone holding a grudge. Unfair, but who cares...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use continue as a name of a variable. It's one of java reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `continue` as a variable name because it is a reserved word.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html):

> The `continue` statement skips the current iteration of a `for`, `while`, or `do-while` loop. The unlabeled form skips to the end of the innermost loop's body and evaluates the boolean expression that controls the loop.

You can tell that it is a keyword because, when you look at your question, `continue` has syntax highlighting applied, like `boolean` and `false`.

```
boolean continue = false;
```

That would be like writing

```
boolean boolean = false;
```

or

```
boolean false = false;
```

Both of those obviously won't work, so try something else like `continuing`:

```
boolean continuing = false;
```